# Peewee query to fetch all records on a specific date

Tags: python, peewee

I'm using Peewee as my ORM. I have a DateTimeField and I want to fetch all records that occur on a certain date:

```
event_date = '2018-04-18'
event_date_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(event_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

I know I can take a datetime object and fetch all the records greater than that and less than the next day:

```
list(Event.select().where((Event.event_date > event_date_dt) & (Event.event_date < event_date_dt + datetime.timedelta(days=1))))
```

However, this feels very hacky. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered the following solution in the [peewee docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/query_examples.html#work-out-the-start-times-of-bookings-for-tennis-courts):

```
from peewee import fn
list(Event.select().where(fn.date_trunc('day', Event.event_date) == event_date_dt))
```